# How to use a powershell script during vagrant up on host correctly?

Tags: powershell, vagrant, hyper-v

I am trying to execute a powershell script during vagrant up privileged and with elevated rights. I am using Vagrant 2.2.10 on an windows machine. The script lies in the same directory like the Vagrantfile. i have managed to get the correct trigger, but wasn't able to execute my powershell script correct with trigger.run.

Here is the relevant part of my Vagrantfile:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_EXPERIMENTAL'] = "typed_triggers"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
override.trigger.before :'VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance', type: :action do |trigger|
          trigger.ruby do |env, machine|
            machine.ui.info("------------------ Configure Node with Powershell Script -------------------")            
            trigger.run = {
              #privileged: "true"
              #powershell_elevated_interactive: "true"
              inline: <<-SHELL
              echo hhhhhhh > 123.log
              Write-Host "test"
              SHELL
           }            
           trigger.run = { path: './test.ps1'}
           trigger.run = { inline: "./test.ps1 -a 'test1' -b 'test2" }
           trigger.run = { privileged: "true",  powershell_elevated_interactive: "true", path: "powershell test.ps1", args: ["-a test1", "-b test2 "] }
           #trigger.run = { privileged: "true",  powershell_elevated_interactive: "true", :path => "test.ps1", :args => "testarg1, testarg2"} 
              
           machine.ui.info("------------------ Configuration of Node finished  -------------------") 
          end
        end 
    
      end
```

In the vagrant.log i couldn't find any specific error that could help:

```
 INFO trigger: Firing trigger for action VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance on guest server1
 INFO interface: info: Running action triggers before VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance ...
 INFO interface: info: ==> server1: Running action triggers before VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance ...
==> server1: Running action triggers before VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance ...
DEBUG trigger: Running trigger 69600289-3cee-4dde-a9fa-2ac9bec33409...
 INFO interface: info: Running trigger...
 INFO interface: info: ==> server1: Running trigger...
==> server1: Running trigger...
 INFO interface: info: ------------------ Configure Node with Powershell Script -------------------
 INFO interface: info: ==> server1: ------------------ Configure Node with Powershell Script -------------------
==> server1: ------------------ Configure Node with Powershell Script -------------------
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined: 
 INFO interface: info: ------------------ Configuration of Node finished  -------------------
 INFO interface: info: ==> server1: ------------------ Configuration of Node finished  -------------------
==> server1: ------------------ Configuration of Node finished  -------------------
```

None of the above trigger.runs worked. Hopefully anybody of you know how to fix this !!

How can i get this work ?

Thanks..

Comment: Why use a trigger for this instead of a provisioner?

Comment: Isn 't the provisoner used on the guest machine ? I want to execute a script within the same directory of the vagrantfile on the host.. Or can the provisioner used locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I use it to overcome the limitations of vagrant and add an additional network card to a different second public switch. You can use it to execute any powershell script:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_EXPERIMENTAL'] = "typed_triggers"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  
    # Set ImageName
    config.vm.box = "REPO/YOURIMAGE"    
    config.vm.box_version  ="YOURVERSION"
 
    # Set network to Hyper-V Switch (define an external switch in hyperv and insert here)
    config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "WAN - FIRST"
    
    # Add Additional network card and assign a different second public network
    # THIS DOES NOT WORK ON HYPER-V DUE LIMITATIONS OF VAGRANT 
    #config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "WAN - SECOND"

    # WORKAROUND for all LIMITATIONS OF VAGRANT (execute a powershell script to handle hyper-v actions before startup of instance)
    # will be executed before the hyper-Instance will be started  
    secSwitch ='WAN - SECOND'

    config.vm.provider :hyperv do |vb, override|

    # Set vmname
    vb.vmname = "testmachine"
    # Execute a powershell script elevated and privileged (!!)
      override.trigger.before :'VagrantPlugins::HyperV::Action::StartInstance', type: :action do |trigger|
        trigger.run = { inline: "./hyperv-config-node.ps1 -VmName testmachine -SwitchName \"'#{secSwitch}'\" " }
      end
    end 
    # WORKAROUND (END)
end
```

and the powershell scripts hyperv-config-node.ps1 looks like this:

```
param (
    [parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$VmName,
    [parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SwitchName
)

try {
  Write-Host "------------------ Configure Node with Powershell Script : $VmName -------------------"
  Write-Host "VM-Machine: $VmName"
  Write-Host "Add Switch: $SwitchName"
  $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  Write-Host "IsAdmin: " $currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
  $vm = Hyper-V\Get-VM -Name $VmName -ErrorAction "stop" 
  Hyper-V\Add-VMNetworkAdapter $vm -Switch $SwitchName  
  Write-Host "------------------ Configuration of Node finished  -------------------"
}
catch {
  Write-Host "Failed to set VM's Second Nic: $_"
}
```